# perl deleting a subdirectory containing a file of specified format

Tags: perl

i have to do a program in perl. and im very new to it.the task is 
there will be directory ,inside that many subdirectories will be there.each subdirectories contain further subdirectories. finally there will be files in the end of chain of subdirectories. If the file format is ".TXT" i should delete the  subdirectory that is next to the main directory that contains the .TXT file.

for eg  raghav\abc\ccd\1.txt then i should delete subdirectory "abc".

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Cwd qw(abs_path);


my $path ="d:\\raghav";

search_all_folder($path);

sub search_all_folder {
    my ($folder) = @_;
    if ( -d $folder ) {
        chdir $folder;
        opendir my $dh, $folder or die "can't open the directory: $!";
        while ( defined( my $file = readdir($dh) ) ) {
            chomp $file;
            next if $file eq '.' or $file eq '..';
            search_all_folder("$folder/$file");  ## recursive call
            read_files($file) if ( -f $file );
        }
        closedir $dh or die "can't close directory: $!";
    }
}

sub read_files {
    my ($filename) = @_;

    if($filename= ~/.txt/)
    rmdir;
    }
}
```

Comment: question: what if d:\rhagav does not contain a file? seems like you are opening it and calling search_all_folder while there are files?

Comment: no d:\raghav folder contains subfolders.inside subfolders files will be present

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never ever implement your own directory traversal. Use [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.4/lib/File/Find.pm) instead. It's more efficient and less prone to breaking.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

my $search_path = "d:\\raghav";
my %text_files_found_in;

sub find_text_files {
    if (m/\.txt$/i) {
        ## you may want to transform this first, to get a higher level directory. 
        $text_files_found_in{$File::Find::dir}++;
    }
}

find( \&find_text_files, $search_path );

foreach my $dir ( keys %text_files_found_in ) {
    print "$dir contained a text file\n"; 
    ##maybe delete it, but don't until you're sure the code's working!
}
```

You've got a list of files now, against which you can figure out what to delete and then delete it. `rmdir` won't do the trick though - that only works on empty directories. You can either collate a list of files (as this does) or you could figure out the path to delete as you go, and insert it into a hash. (So you don't get dupes).

Either way though - it's probably better to run the find first, delete second rather than trying to delete a tree you may still be traversing.

Edit: What this program does:

- Imports the File::Find module.
- defines the subroutine `find_text_files`
- runs `find` (in the File::Find module), and tells it to run `find_text_files` on every file it finds in it's recursive traversal.
- `find_text_files` is called on every file within the triee (below `$search_path`). When it's called:

  - `File::Find` sets: `$_` to be the current filename. We match against `m/\.txt$/` to see if it's a text file.
  - `File::Find` also sets two other variables: `$File::Find::dir` - to the directory path to this file. And `$File::Find::file` to the full file path. We insert `$File::Find::dir` into the hash `text_files_found_in` provided that pattern matches.
- Once `find` is complete, we have a hash called `text_files_found_in` which contains keys of all the directories where a text file was found.
- we can then iterate on `keys %text_files_found_in` to identify - and delete.*
- at this point, you may want to transform each of the directories in that list, because it'll be a full path to the file, and you may only want to delete at a higher level.

* There's no delete code in this script - you'll have to sort that yourself. I'm not putting anything that might delete stuff up on the internet where people who don't full understand it might just run it blind.

Comment: i directly have to remove the subdirectory that contains the .txt file.how can i do it?

Comment: `$File::Find::dir` - within the find subroutine - is the path to the file. Put that into a hash (to avoid duplicates). (Answer updated)

Comment: thank you so much.. m not getting the logic of program u have given, can you pls give algorithm, and also file::find im not used it

Comment: thanks alot,:) i am getting a syntax error near   $text_files_found_in{$File:Find::dir}++;;

Comment: pls tel me what is it

Comment: Needs another ":" `$File::Find::dir`